# Why is In-App-Purchase being restored?

Tags: macos, cocoa, in-app-purchase, restore

I have a Consumable in-app-purchase in my OS X app that purchases a certain number of coins. However, the second time I purchase the consumable, I get an alert saying that the item has already been purchased and will be restored for free.

Why is this happening with a consumable in-app-purchase?

Here is my IAP code:

```
typealias RequestProductsCompletionHandler = ([SKProduct]?) -> Void

class IAPHelper: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate{

    private var productsRequest: SKProductsRequest?
    private var completionHandler: RequestProductsCompletionHandler!
    private let productIdentifiers: Set<String>
    private var purchasedProductIdentifiers = Set<String>()

    init(productIdentifiers: Set<String>){
        self.productIdentifiers = productIdentifiers
        super.init()
        for identifier in productIdentifiers{
            let productPurchased = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(identifier)
            if productPurchased{
                purchasedProductIdentifiers.insert(identifier)
            }
        }
    }

    func requestProducts(completionHandler: RequestProductsCompletionHandler){
        self.completionHandler = completionHandler
        productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
        productsRequest?.delegate = self
        productsRequest?.start()
    }

    // MARK: SKProductsRequestDelegate

    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
        productsRequest = nil
        let skProducts = response.products as! [SKProduct]
        completionHandler(skProducts)
        completionHandler = nil
    }

    func request(request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        productsRequest = nil
        print("Error: \(error)\nDescription: \(error.description)")
        completionHandler(nil)
        completionHandler = nil
    }

    func buyProduct(product: SKProduct){
        let payment = SKPayment.paymentWithProduct(product) as! SKPayment
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)
    }

    func productPurchased(productIdentifier: String) -> Bool{
        return purchasedProductIdentifiers.contains(productIdentifier)
    }
}

extension IAPHelper: SKPaymentTransactionObserver{
    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
        for transaction in transactions as! [SKPaymentTransaction]{
            switch transaction.transactionState{
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                completeTransaction(transaction)
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                failedTransaction(transaction)
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    func completeTransaction(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction){
        provideContentForProductIdentifier(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
    }

    func failedTransaction(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction){
        if let errorCode = transaction.error?.code where errorCode != SKErrorPaymentCancelled{
            print(transaction.error!.localizedDescription)
        }
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
    }

    func provideContentForProductIdentifier(productIdentifier: String){
        //Override in subclass
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you're having this specific issue, but are you aware that your `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` implementation is wrong? You must take account of _all_ possibilities. You must handle the `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` case by calling `finishTransaction`. You should do that even if you think that this can never happen.

Comment: @matt I didn't think I needed the other cases because I only have consumables in the app.

Comment: Also, you're finishing the transaction incorrectly in your `completeTransaction`. Your job is to say `finishTransaction` _to the payment queue_ that arrives in `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:`. You are _assuming_ that this is the same as the `defaultQueue()`. Don't assume that. Pass the queue to `completeTransaction` (and to `failedTransaction` so that you know you are talking to this queue instance.

Comment: "I didn't think I needed" Maybe you do, maybe you don't. What I'm saying is: if you want to program iOS successfully, _assume nothing_. If the docs say to do a thing, do _that thing_ and no other.

Comment: @matt OK, thanks for your help!

Comment: It really sounds like it must be an issue in iTunes -- you're totally sure the IAP is a consumable?

Comment: @BenFlynn Yes, it's definitely consumable (just checked in iTC)

Comment: If you restart the app after making a purchase, does it try to make the purchase again when you start observing the payment queue? If so, somehow finish purchase is probably failing. If not, I might try creating a new iTunes test user and trying again as sometimes they get into strange states.

Comment: @BenFlynn I already created a second user, still happening :/ And the purchase is finished properly.